# Meteor-reddit oauth error ["message::"Forbidden", "error":403]

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I am getting the following error when I try to add reddit login service. The app however get registered to the user after the login process. But I dont have a new user account setup in meteor after the login process. Was wondering if anyone else has experience with this.
["message::"Forbidden", "error":403]

Comment: Did you set up your config correctly? Can you add parts of your code which are connected with reddit login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use https://oauth.reddit.com/api/v1/me. not https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/me.

Apart from that everything else worked as it was supposed to.